# Overlapping many imgs in html

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have 7 transparent images all with the same width and same height. Then I have a background image with the same width and height as well. What I did (and want to do) is to place the background image in the main div and place all the other 7 imgs on top as you see in the code below. But the result is that the imgs actually flow out of the main div and are bigger. I tried changing my css but similar behaviour alway occurs. In addition, the background image is not in the center of the page like specified in the css. 
What can be my mistake?

So I got the following html:

```
 <div class="row wrapper">
      <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.firstDisplay.src}}"></div>
      <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.secondDisplay.src}}"></div>
      <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.thirdDisplay.src}}"></div>
      <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.forthDisplay.src}}"></div>
      <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.fifthDisplay.src}}"></div>
      <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.sixthDisplay.src}}"></div>
      <div class="col container"><img ng-src="{{data.seventhDisplay.src}}"></div>
    </div>
```

And the following css:

```
img {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding:0;
max-width: 100%;}

.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;}

.wrapper {
    padding-right:20%;
    padding-left:20%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 127px;
    background: url(img/Tbackg.png)  no-repeat center;
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
```

The output looks like (note that not all images appear here but the point is shown, the background is the small image while the big ones are the individual images):
[image]

Comment: can you copy the html output?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle or codepen for this?

Comment: What is the size of the background image and the ones to be on top?

Comment: All of them are originally 700 by 527 but i am resizing it in the css as you can see @LGSon

Comment: Well there lays the problem, since your container is 127px high and you size the img using percent based on width. Check my 2:nd sample, it will solve your problem

Comment: it did overlay them nicely, however the div is still no in the center of the page, its a bit closer to the left... @LGSon

Comment: If you check my 2:nd sample it does the job, still, if you have additional settings not present here that might affect the layout, please post an update, or a link to the site and I'll have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element with `margin: auto` need a width, but in your case, drop the margin and set `text-align: center;` on the parent `.container` instead

*If the `img` images height is not the same as the height set on the wrapper, you'll need to add `height: 100%`, or else they will not match the backgrond image's height*

```css
img {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;            /*  needed if image is higher/lower than
                               the 127px set on the wrapper  */
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper {
  padding-right: 20%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 127px;
  background: yellow url(http://placehold.it/127) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row wrapper">
  <div class="col container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/227/f00">
  </div>
  <div class="col container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/227/0f0">
  </div>
  <div class="col container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/227/00f">
  </div>
</div>
```

As suggestion would be to drop the `img` in favor of using a background image on the container. By doing so, the image will adjust equally with how `background-size: contain` works

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;  
}
.wrapper {
  padding-right: 20%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 127px;
  background: yellow url(http://placehold.it/127) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row wrapper">
  <div class="col container"
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/127/f00)">
  </div>
  <div class="col container"
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/127/0f0)">
  </div>
  <div class="col container"
       style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/127/00f)">
  </div>
</div>
```